# ReferenceError: window is not defined "at AuthService.8klp.AuthService.init"

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm

Outside the Docker Application is working fine when I am trying to build using Dockerfile and run the container I am getting the above issue.

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
at AuthService.8klp.AuthService.init (/usr/local/iquanta-ang/dist/server/main.js:93765:9)
at new AuthService (/usr/local/iquanta-ang/dist/server/main.js:93760:14)
at AuthService_Factory (/usr/local/iquanta-ang/dist/server/main.js:93800:108)
at _callFactory (/usr/local/iquanta-ang/dist/server/main.js:75898:24)
at _createProviderInstance (/usr/local/iquanta-ang/dist/server/main.js:75856:30)
at resolveNgModuleDep (/usr/local/iquanta-ang/dist/server/main.js:75831:21)
at NgModuleRef_.get (/usr/local/iquanta-ang/dist/server/main.js:76507:20)
at resolveDep (/usr/local/iquanta-ang/dist/server/main.js:76878:49)
at createClass (/usr/local/iquanta-ang/dist/server/main.js:76758:36)
at createDirectiveInstance (/usr/local/iquanta-ang/dist/server/main.js:76629:24)
```

This issue was because recently we have implemented Google Gmail Login POP Up on our website.
After implementing the Gmail Login POP UP on our website issue has started on Docker Container.
Is there any dependencies need to be installed for "window is not defined"
Can someone please help me to fix this issue.
Here is my Dockerfile.

```
`FROM node:16 as dev-build
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH=$PATH:/home/node/.npm-global/bin 
WORKDIR /usr/local/angular/
COPY . /usr/local/angular
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install pm2 -g
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build:ssr
RUN npm run-script build
CMD ["pm2-runtime","/usr/local/angular/dist/server.js"]
EXPOSE 4000`
```

Regards
Sainath

Comment: Try comparing your local and docker versions to ensure that all your dependencies are properly used by docker as mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/496#issuecomment-321547298)

Comment: I had verified and see both the dependencies are same comparing the local and docker.